# Magento 2 Store email addresses not editable

Tags: magento2.2, admin-panel, order-email

So, in Magento 2 under:

> Stores > config > General > Store Email addresses

I want to edit the **Sales Representative** email address, however, it seems to be disabled - the store is currently set into single store mode. I'm running Magento 2.2.5 on a php7.1 box in production mode.

I've not been able to modify these email addresses before, if I remove the **disabled** via the inspect DOM modifier, I can edit them and then on save it resets to the example .... but updates the database.

Here's a quick screengrab.

[image]

I simply can't edit them, I'm at a loss, I don't know why it works in a local environment but doesn't work on the server.

I'd just like to point out it works on a local machine but not on the live one.

Comment: is there any custom module related to `toggleValueElements` OR `adminhtml/tools.js`JS?

Comment: Nope. Not this, and just point out again it works locally but not on live.

Comment: did you done required commands like static content deploy and cache flush?

Comment: yes. Redeployed after disabling modules to no affect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So. If you come across this issue, its related to your env.php file. The config has been exported to the env and is overwriting the admin area meaning you can't edit it.

```
    trans_email' => [
            'ident_custom1' => [
                'email' => 'example@example.com',
                'name' => 'Custom 1 Info'
            ],
            'ident_custom2' => [
                'email' => 'example@example.com',
                'name' => 'Custom 2 Info'
            ],
            'ident_general' => [
                'email' => 'example@example.com',
                'name' => 'Owner'
            ],
            'ident_sales' => [
                'email' => 'example@example.com',
                'name' => 'Sales'
            ],
            'ident_support' => [
                'email' => 'example@example.com',
                'name' => 'CustomerSupport'
            ]
        ],
```

If anyone has the same issue know it will be here ^_^

If you decide to remove or edit this bit of code. You will have to execute `bin/magento setup:upgrade` or `bin/magento app:config:import` after modifying it.